# HTML Form Text to Speech speaks the file name and PHP, Doubles Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am working on a webpage that takes HTML form input, processes it on a loop using PHP, then displays the PHP echo output in a `div` using jQuery, then TTS speaks a message using ResponsiveVoiceJS.
The problem that is visible right now is that, upon loading of the page, the TTS starts speaking the webpage file name and some random PHP on a loop, then displays the form twice.
It shouldn't do any of that!

Since I am not sure which part of the code is causing the issue, here is the code in its entirety:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>" method="post">
What is your URL? <input type="text" name="pastedurl"><br>
What is your minimum interval? <input type="text" name="interval"><br>
<input type ="submit">
</form> 
<?php
set_time_limit(18000);
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    // echo "stopped here";
    // die;  //THIS DOESN'T WORK EITHER
    $pastedlink  = $_POST['pastedurl'];
    $pastedlink2 = $_POST['pastedurl'];
    $rate        = $_POST['interval'];
    parse_url($_POST['pastedurl'], PHP_URL_HOST);
    if (parse_url($_POST['pastedurl'], PHP_URL_HOST) == 'www.instructables.com')
      {
        for ($z = 0; $z < 2880; $z++)
          {
            $tutorial_json  = file_get_contents($pastedlink);
            $tutorial_array = json_decode($tutorial_json, true);
            $oldviews       = $tutorial_array['views'];
            sleep(30);
            $tutorial_json2  = file_get_contents($pastedlink);
            $tutorial_array2 = json_decode($tutorial_json2, true);
            $currentviews    = $tutorial_array2['views'];
            $viewcount1      = (int) $oldviews;
            $viewcount2      = (int) $currentviews;
            $change          = $viewcount2;
            $change -= $viewcount1;
            $rateasint = (int) $rate;
            if ($change >= $rateasint)
              {
                $sayit = "Alert!  Your Tutorial has gained " . $change . " more views";
                echo $sayit;
              }
          }
      }
    else
      {
        exit("Error: URL submitted was not from www.instructables.com");
      }
  }
?> 
 <script src="http://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(readyEvent) {
                speakInnerHTML();
            });
            function speakInnerHTML() {
                var speek = document.getElementById("load_updates");
                responsiveVoice.speak(speek.innerHTML);
            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var auto_refresh = setInterval(
            function ()
            {
                $('#load_updates').load('<?php
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>',speakInnerHTML).fadeIn("slow");
            }, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
         </script>
                <div id="load_updates"> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Sorry about the poor formatting, I am a noob and don't know the methods of formatting these programming languages!

Here is a video of the error in action:
[youtube](https://youtu.be/8usK4GDlWNM)

Comment: You video is private.

Comment: Hi Aaron. My error, the video is viewable now

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

```
die;  //THIS DOESN'T WORK EITHER
```

`die()` is a function, and despite the wonders of `echo`, all functions are called with parentheses.

**2.**

```
isset($_POST['submit'])
```

This doesn't work because there are variables with the name `submit`.

To fix that, add the name attribute to your submit control, like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

**3.** You are loading the page itself with jQuery, even though it contains... well... itself. It's going to recursively fill the page with its own instances every 10000ms. And every one of that instance is going to do that too. You need to query the page with the data from the form, not just load it. And add a conditional so that if there is $_POST data, the page does not display all the HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I just separate the PHP from the html/js into two separate files then use `.get()` instead of `.load()`?  What do you mean by "so the page does not display all the HTML."?

Comment: I actually tried to refactor your code and add it to the answer, but gave up halfway. Nothing there is going to work at all. You need a separate PHP script that will query the external JSON and print out the current views and a JS script that will regularly query your PHP script and check if the number of views is changed since the last check.

Comment: What would such a JS script look like, and how would I integrate it into the page which should contain the html form, tts, and `div` output?